# Fill Single Input Based On Prior Select - MYSQL PHP JS?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I want to grab my customers phone number from a MYSQL database and auto populate it into an input box based on users selection of customers in a prior dropdown box.

I've managed to do this in the past when filling in larger amounts of data but what I've previously used seems like a lot of code to auto fill a single input box.

I know how to fill the customer phone based on the data passed from the prior page (although I've deleted that bit here) but I want that data to change dynamically as users use the dropdown.

There's got to be an easy way to do this but I'm a complete newb at js (and only barely proficient at PHP & MYSQL). Can anyone give me a hand?

My PHP/HTML:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT cust_id, name, phone FROM customers ORDER BY name ASC");
$customers = mysql_fetch_array($result);

<label for="customer">Customer:</label>
<select name="customer">
    <option value="0">Add New Customer</option>
        <? foreach ($customers as $customer): ?>
            <option value="<?=$customer['cust_id']?>" <?=($customer['cust_id'] == $parts['cust']) ? "selected" : ""?>><?=$customer['name']?></option>
        <? endforeach; ?>
</select>

<label for="custphone">Customer Phone:</label>
<input type="text" name="custphone" value="">
```

Let me know if you need anything else from me and thanks in advance for helping me out on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this answer, I will use the jQuery syntax, jQuery is a free javascript library, and you'll certainly use it in the future, [read more](http://jquery.com/).
To resume, we'll use an event triggered by your `select` element, when his value is changed, we'll process an AJAX request with some parameters to a PHP page (ajax.php) which returns the phone number of the customer previously choosen.

First you need to include in your HTML web page, the jQuery script, with the `<script>` tag.

```
<script src="path/to/jquery.js"></script>
```

In a second time, we'll create a new javascript script (assuming you add some id's to your HTML elements):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){ // When the document is ready
         $("select#customers").on("change",function(){ // We attach the event onchange to the select element
             var customer_id = this.value; // We retirve the customer's id
             $.ajax({
                 url : "path/to/ajax.php", // path to you php file which returns the phone number
                 method : "post", // We want a POST request 
                 data : "customer_id="+customer_id, // You'll retrieve this data in your $_POST variable in ajax.php : $_POST['customer_id']
                 success: function(response) { // The function to execute if the request is a -success-, response will be the customer phone number
                     $("input#custphone").value(response); // Fill the phone number input 
                 }
             });
         });
    });
</script>
```

Now, you've all the gear to continue, you should read about [jQuery](http://jquery.com) and [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AJAX).
You just have to create the "ajax.php", retrieve your customer id with the `$_POST` variable, process the SQL query to retrieve the phone number, then, return it with an `echo`.

Comment: This is, approximately, the method I've used in the past for this type of functionality. I thought it would be a bit excessive to create a new page (path/to/ajax.php) to simply switch out the one field. I figured there would an easier way to pull this off without having a new page each time I want to have any kind of functionality of this sort. Thank you for your answer and input. Is this the only real way to do this and if not would it be possible for path/to/ajax.php to handle the functionality for all my instances of using a dropdown to determine text farther down the page?

Comment: You can make it handle other things, too. Just add the "what" to the `data` part of the request. So if you have something like `what=customerinfo` and `customer_id=1` then you know to get customer info for customer 1. If the "what" is something else, return something else.

Comment: So I pass a "category" parameter of some sort and then run a switch or if statement to figure out what to switch out. Rock & roll. Thanks.

Comment: In theory I understand how this is supposed to work. I get it. In practice, I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I've placed the javascript above everywhere but in my <head>. I have no typos in the link to my ajax.php page. On my ajax.php page I can even change to GET method and pass the parameters in the URL and it works. For some reason it won't dump the data into the input#custphone field (and yes, I did add that id to that input). Do I want to just echo the phone number on the ajax.php page or output the whole <input>? Either way, I've tried both, not working. Wut up wit dat?

Comment: I agree with @sachleen for the "category parameter". In your case, your 2 solutions can work (echo the phone number, or the input)., but I think echoing the phone number is more simple. What is not working ? Did you tried to retrieve the content of `response` ? Can you post it ?

Comment: My ajax.php page is working, or at least it is when I switch it to $_GET method. I did not alter the code you gave me except to point the URL at the right place. I'm not sure what you're asking when you say "did you try to retrieve the content of 'response'". As far as what's not working, I don't exactly know. I'm not getting any visible errors or jumbled code or anything like that, but nothing changes. The 'id="custphone"' input just stays blank. Thanks for the help and sorry for not having a better understanding of what I'm doing with the ajax.

Comment: @NickHogan Could you post your ajax.php page ?

Comment: I've tried a number of different versions of this page. This is my current iteration.
`<?php
 require("../includes/config.php");

 $customer_id = $_POST['customer_id'];

 
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM customers WHERE cust_id = '$customer_id'");

 $phone = "<input id='custphone' class='' type='text' name='custphone' value='" . $customer['phone'] . "'>";
 
 echo $phone;
?>`

Comment: If you arre echoing the input element, you have to change your success function. I mean you don't have to change the value of the input `custphone`, but you have to append your input element to your form !

Comment: Finally got this sorry bastard to work. I took a slightly different route on the front side than what you recommended my ajax.php page stayed the same and this is what I put on the initial page:  `$(document).ready(function(){ // When the document is ready
    $("#customers").change(function(){ 
        $.post("http://www.practicedomain.com/test/ajax/ajax.php", { customer_id : $("#customers").val() }, function(response){
            $("#custphone").val(response);
            },
            "text"
        );
        return false;
    });
});`

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to look into [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29). [`jQuery.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) makes it pretty easy.

Basically, you have a page on the server that queries the database and returns a [JSON encoded](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) string that the javascript can convert (using [`jQuery.parseJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/))back into an array and populate the list!

Use [`.change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) to bind an event to the dropdown's change event. This will fire whenever the selection changes. Inside, you want to get the value (see demo on that page) and send an AJAX request to the server.

The PHP script on the server will query the database and return a JSON string. In the `success` function of the jQuery AJAX block you can populate the new list with the decoded information. See [this page](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-add-option-select-jquery/) for a tutorial on how to add items to a select.

Comment: I've been looking into AJAX and jQuery/JSON but I've been having a hard time wrapping my head around it.